# My 2 PCs got same MAC addresses, how to fix?

Tags: ip, local-area-network, mac

I have several PCs in my small shop, are connected as a LAN. I really don’t what this happened but today I noticed that one of PC’s softwares (teamspeak) cannot connect to other PC which runs a team speak server. I also got similar  issue with some softwares between these 2 PCs.
I thought maybe need to reinstall those softwares but nothing changed.
I just accidentally noticed that those both PCs have same IP in my LAN & both are 192.168.0.3.
I also noticed they both have same physical MAC address.

I’m not sure about MAC address but I’m sure each one of my PCs had a different local IP before this problem.
I tried to reset router that PCs are connected via that, resetting firewall on problematic 2 PCs and etc, but nothing changed.

Please help I really can’t afford to buy a new MB for one of those PCs to fix this issue (and I’m not even sure this will help).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to change MAC-address in NIC configuration.

Comment: Both motherboard network interfaces have the same ethernet hardware address from the manufacturer?! You should definitely name and shame the manufacturer/model!

Comment: Alexander how can I exactly change the MAC address can u be more specific?

Comment: David I’m not sure what it ethernet harsware address is, but it’s a acer q67h2-am motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I changed MAC address via device manager & now everything works fine.